# Same number of provable as unprovable statements?

Tags: incompleteness

Building on this question:
[Infinitely many nonequivalent unprovable statements in ZFC because of Gödel's incompleteness theorem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1493486/infinitely-many-nonequivalent-unprovable-statements-in-zfc-because-of-g%C3%B6dels-in)

is the infinity of provable statements the same infinity of unprovable statements, or are there more unprovable statements?

I am wondering if there is anything we can say about the probability that a random true statement is provable....

Comment: Each is $\aleph_0$ - there are only countably many statements, after all.

Comment: thanks! of course.. so I guess we don't have any clues to the "ratio" of provable to unprovable statements?

Comment: There is not a very good way to define the ratio of the size of two sets with the same infinite cardinality. We can talk about the density of sets if there is a topology, but I don't know of any topology on the space of all statements.

Comment: I am naive in this area - so the argument that there are twice as many natural numbers as even numbers would be a topological argument?

Comment: @dashnick There aren't twice as many natural numbers as there are even numbers. The evens are in bijection with the naturals, so their cardinality is the same

Comment: Right, technically.. But in some sense of course there are twice as many - would that be a density argument?  (In the sense that a random number has 2x the chance of being natural as being even)